# Nginx URL rewrite regex

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I've switched over from Apache to Nginx. A very smooth and trouble free process, until I had to sort out a .htaccess file I have, and now I am stumped.

I understand that Nginx does this differently and that this needs to be done in the config file (within a `location /{code here}` entry) using regex and the built-in `rewrite` function but I cannot figure it out!

I need to convert a URL request from this:

```
http://example.com/datasources/apis/v1/login.php
```

To:

```
http://example.com/datasources/apis/API_controller.php/v1/login.php
```

The PHP script will vary and there will sometimes be some variables in the URL (as in a GET request)

A steer in the right direction would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
location ^~ /datasources/apis/v1/ {
    rewrite ^/datasources/apis/v1/(.*) /datasources/apis/API_controller.php/v1/$1;
}
```